# CakePHP How to redirect to dashboard by users id

Tags: cakephp

After user login to the system, based on user_id, forward to their own dashboard, the url should be like ...../dashboard/userid, 
the dashboard will display for example the latest orders which the user placed not others

I read [How to build a “dashboard” for your application in CakePHP.](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/12/16/how-to-build-a-dashboard-for-your-application-in-cakephp/)

but it is same for all users
How can I map $userid to /dashboard?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is correct design. You should have a universal url for all user dashboards (/dashboard) and use the Auth component to retrieve the user_id and display based on that.

```
$user_id = $this->Auth->user('id');
$orders = $this->Order->findByUserId($user_id);
```

Comment: Yes, this. Just make a single dashboard action (or maybe a dashboard controller with an index action, whatever you want) and have it use the id of the currently authenticated user. If you did it the way you initially suggested, either users could access another user's dashboard by changing the URL, or you'd have to test for their ID being equal to the parameter they passed in anyways, so just do it this way.

Comment: thanks, I think i should make two dashboards, one for customers, one for admin, then follow your advice, it makes sense. thanks again

Comment: Yes, a separate dashboard for all customers, and one for admin is the way to go. You're welcome. (remember to accept the answer :o))

Answer (score 1):

Fore redirection you could do:

```
$this->redirect(
    array(
       "controller"   => "dashboard",
       "action"       => "index",
       $user_id
    )
);
```

Did you mean something like this